# Finding the unconditional distribuition of a variable

Tags: distributions, conditional-distribution

Im solving Gibbs sampler related questions and Im trying to find the unconditional distribuition of $\beta | \lambda \sim N(0, \lambda^{-1}\Sigma)$ knowing that $\lambda \sim Gamma(\frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{\alpha}{2})$. I know that the resulting distribuition of beta will be a multivariate $t$ with $(\mu, \Sigma, \alpha)$, but I don't know how to get there. How do I find the distribuition of $\beta$?

Comment: How does the Gibbs sampler come into the question? Your body text seems to be asking about how to derive that it's multivariate-t.

Comment: Im solving questions related to the Gibbs sampler, you have a good point, I was working on it and it seems that I don't need the Gibbs sampler to solve it.

Comment: You should definitely tag this *self-study* and see the tag wiki info. Note that $f(\beta) = \int_0^\infty f(\beta|\lambda) f(\lambda) d\lambda$ (though you may find it easier to work with the distribution of $\lambda^{-1}$ instead). From there it's reasonably simple manipulation. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: You may find this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse-gamma_distribution useful, as well as the illustration of completing the square ... e.g. similar to what's done here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140540/bayesian-linear-model-posterior-as-sum-of-squares ... There are some derivations on site (I am sure I wrote one at some stage but there are others), so try a search. Failing that there are multiple sets of notes that discuss it such as here: http://web.archive.org/web/20170828154305/http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/7440/BayesianLinearModelGoryDetails.pdf

Comment: also see here: https://bookdown.org/aramir21/IntroductionBayesianEconometricsGuidedTour/linear-regression-the-conjugate-normal-normalinverse-gamma-model.html